Continuous Data Fetch
I’m working on food delivery app, as a personal project to learn React Native I’ve build the client-side app that fetches the menu from a db and inserts the order into the db..
Now I want to create the restaurant-side app and whenever an order is inserted into the db the main page should be refreshed and the restaurant must be able to chose if accept or decline the order but I don’t really now how to do this
I’ve tried a useEffect but obviously it fetches data only once, I’ve also tried the setInterval but in my opinion it is inefficient

I think websocket will be good for you. Is that right ?

That’s the proper way https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching

@antokhio This is not the proper way to solve this case as you cannot have an app continuously doing requests, that will break the app. That's for re-fetching in a case it's needed because of the change of a variable and also in this case there are 2 apps that needs to "communicate" between them using the server

For that use case, you should use WebSockets. Here's the react native documentation about WebSockets, but essentially it offers a bidirectional communication between server and client so that you can get the the fetch from the first app through HTTP/HTTPS, receive it in the server and send a message through WS/WSS to a channel (you can subscribe as many restaurants as you want to it) to the restaurant app with the information needed and you can show the accept or decline buttons without any problem.
Hope this helps!
